# How can I enforce an UILabel to be wider than it should be, by 5 points?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have an UILabel, it has background color as green. But It wraps the text very closely. I need the green background to be little wider than the text, approx 5 points. How can I achieve this?

**Details**

Label is created in storyboard and has horizontal spacing constraints. You can ignore the constraints as I guess, because I have handled it for any width.

**Suggested Requirement**

I guess I need a method which I can override in my UILabel's subclass, to increase its width by 5 points. Anybody knows which method I shoul override?

Comment: Are making a label programatically ?

Comment: Please, explain your problem with more details. Maybe you can just adjust it's width?

Comment: Gentlemen, please check the edits

Comment: I solved it. Please check my answer for reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem! It works great like this -

Make a subclass of `UILabel` and override the `intrinsicContentSize` and `sizeThatFits` to achieve what you want.

So, something like:

```
- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize
{
    return [self addHorizontalPadding:[super intrinsicContentSize]];
}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{
    return [self addHorizontalPadding:[super intrinsicContentSize]];
}

- (CGSize)addHorizontalPadding:(CGSize)size
{
    if (size.width > 0)
        return CGSizeMake(size.width + (2*kSomeHorizontalPaddingValue), size.height);
    else
        return size;
}
```

Note that this only touches the horizontal padding, but can obviously be modified to add vertical padding as well.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to subclassing of UILabel class and overriding below method  -

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 5, 0, 5};
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

Hope this will be help you !

Comment: Thanks. This worked well. And anyways I wanted to subClass the UILabel class.

Comment: It has a small issue... It is not making my Label wider, but the area of text smaller... which cuts my tail ends.

Comment: In this case you have increase width of your label width . Its more likely padding not margin , its included inside of UILabel

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by calling sizeToFit first, it will shrink the frame and fit to text, then you can increase width by 10 pixels and remember to keep it center aligned.

Hope it helps.. Let me know... :)

Comment: You need to override sizeThatFits: before calling sizeToFit

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will be working for you

```
CGFloat width =  [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22 ]].width;

label.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, width+5,height);
```